# Woocommerce order delete hook callback is not being called

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm trying to hook a function to the order deletion (when permanently delete is clicked from admin page) but for some reason the function isn't called. My code looks something like

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_delete_order_item', function($id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($id);
    //do some stuff with order meta data
}, 10, 1);
```

I tried to throw and exception inside the function but no error occurred. Can somebody help?

Comment: Are you trying to hook into when an order is deleted or an item is deleted on an order? You're hooking into the item deletion action.

Comment: I'm trying to hook the function after permanently delete is clicked when the order is completed

Comment: You want to apply hook on order delete function ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `woocommerce_before_delete_order_item` action runs every time an item is deleted from an order, not every time an order is deleted. You need to use the `before_delete_post` hook:

```
add_action('before_delete_post', function($id) {
    $post_type = get_post_type($id);

    if ($post_type !== 'shop_order') {
        return;
    }

    $order = new WC_Order($id);
    //do some stuff with order meta data
}, 10, 1);
```

Depending on what it is you want to do, you may want to hook on to the action at an earlier stage by changing the priority argument from `10` to something smaller.

Comment: There is also the `woocommerce_delete_order` hook (Can't tell if its new, but I wanted to mention it for other people who read that)

Comment: @Petschko, it looks like `woocommerce_delete_order` is called _after_ the order is deleted: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/cd70ca68956c6e8a4d9f75885442b42d7a841dcd/includes/data-stores/abstract-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php#L202

Comment: thanks for these Informations, in some case it can be useful to only do stuff _after_ the order is deleted

Answer (score 1):

if you intend to use the **Move to thrash** from the order details page on admin dashboard, you can use the `wp_trash_post`. The `before_delete_post` didn't work for me.

```
function onOrderDelete($orderId){
    $post_type = get_post_type($orderId);
    if($post_type !== 'shop_order') {
        return;
    }
    $order = wc_get_order($orderId);
    // do whatever with $order
}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'onOrderDelete', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function restrict_post_deletion($post_ID){
    $type = get_post_type($post_ID);
    if($type == 'shop_order'){
            $order = new WC_Order($post_ID);
           //do some stuff with order data
    }
}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'restrict_post_deletion', 10, 1);
add_action('before_delete_post', 'restrict_post_deletion', 10, 1);
```

Try this code snippet